# Creating forms in QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image]

If you click on them you can zoom-in in the selected features. I can also search the features.

How can I recreate these objects (form, iframe, div...) in QGIS?

Comment: What is the source of this screenshot ?

Comment: I'ts a screenshot of a document. Someone gave it to me to realise it :S
But, I'm not able to find it out, how they have done it.

Answer (score 4):

In 3.8 is possible to make html form widget. Link to  [YouTube movie](https://youtu.be/u3e_7nRLNIQ)

Basicly you can write fancy html page with animation and so on and add expression or data from layers. Big problem is lack of documentation for it, I learn a little making stop frame from YouTube.

[image: htmlwidget]

Comment: Thank you for yor answer. it looks interesting and I am going to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

With the online material for qgis comes a [training manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html). It describes how to create forms for vector data. The most extensive way is to use the QtDesigner, the form itself is stored as an XML-File, which QGIS can use. After all, the picture above may show a WMS-Layer with a html formular from a GetFeatureInfo-Request. Then the form is done server side and ideed shows HTML.

Comment: Is there any video tutorial? Or any manual with examples?

Comment: I don't know about videos, but there are examples with the link.

Comment: I'm gonna search for it then. Thank you very much for answering